# Reconditioning and Drainage Line ArcHydro

Tags: arc-hydro

I cannot get ArcHydro to run Reconditioning - says object reference not set to an instance of an object.  So, not finding what that refers to, I skipped that and used the sequence of Terrain Preprocessing functions up to Drainage Line Delineation, but that won't run either, giving a message that a grid code is dropped. Does someone know how to get past these roadblocks?

Comment: Could you add some screen shots?